# How to capture the screen shot for transition

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I want to capture the screenshot for the transition between images.

```
- (UIImage *)captureView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);
    [view.layer.presentationLayer renderInContext:ctx];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

I call this method during a UIImageView playing transition of images, however, I just got the still image in the UIImageView but cannot capture the transition between images.
Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

In the simulator you can hit shift 3 times to slow animation down, you might be able to catch the transition then.

Comment: I think u r misunderstood. He need to do it programmatically.:)

Comment: Thanks texian, but I still cannot catch the transition after hit Shift key for 3 times. Anything I missed?